# Nested Recursive Directives with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm learning about Nested Recursive Directives with ng-repeat.
I referenced from

[Building Nested Recursive Directives in Angular](http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/)

then I want the data of level 2 ui template is customize by myself, not just recall or re-render the same template.

For example

```
<ul>
   <li>
     <div>Europe</div>
       <!-- Customize by myself ui of level 2 -->
       <ul>
          <li>
            <div><img src="italy.jpg" /></div>
            <div>Italy</div>
          </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

How do I modify the Directive link function to append new template to level 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is one example:

```
<div style="float: left;">
                            <ul>
                                <li ng-repeat="item in LIST">
                                    <span id="listItems">
                                        {{item.HEADER}}
                                    </span>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li ng-repeat="subitem in item.SUBLIST">
                                            <span id="listItems">
                                                {{subitem.HEADER}}
                                            </span>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

Here LIST will be your first level List and it will have an object SUBLIST for second level list.